# Output variable not getting set in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unit-testing

I hope this is not one of those questions where I slap myself afterwards, but this is really confusing me. I have this working for another one of my stored procedures which is why this is so confusing. It's basically the same setup in both. Here's what's happening.

Here's an example of my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateRecord] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Link1Id INT = NULL,
    @Link2Id INT = NULL,
    @Amount MONEY,
    @Output int out
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Output = 0

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @Link1Id = NULL
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Records WHERE Link2Id = @Link2Id)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Records]
               ([Link1Id]
               ,[Link2Id])
         VALUES
               (@Link1Id
               ,@Link2Id)
        SET @Output = (SELECT RecordId FROM dbo.Records WHERE Link2Id = @Link2Id)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Records WHERE Link1Id = @Link1Id)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Records]
               ([Link1Id]
               ,[Link2Id])
         VALUES
               (@Link1Id
               ,@Link2Id)
        SET @Output = (SELECT RecordId FROM dbo.Records WHERE Link1Id = @Link1Id)
    END
END
```

Now, I have created a unit test that basically runs this procedure, and tries to `Assert` that the returned `@Output` is greater than 0, but the `@Output` parameter never has a value on the `SqlCommand` in the code. Here's some of the C# code:

```
private int ExecuteNonQueryWithOutput(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    SqlCommand command = this.GenerateCommand(procedureName, parameters);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int retval = (int)command.Parameters[OUTPUT].Value;
    connection.Close();

    return retval;
}
```

Now, I can step over the line that calls `ExecuteNonQuery()`, and verify in the database that the new (and correct) record is there, but then on the next line, it throws an exception when it calls `(int)command.Parameters[OUTPUT].Value;` as the `Value` is not there.

This is working perfectly for another procedure that I have which is setup in the same exact fashion. Do you know why it wouldn't be working here?

Thanks, I'm kind of stumped. I've debugged for a while now with no luck.

**Edit:**

Code that generates the parameters array:

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Link1Id", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = link1Val });
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Link2Id", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = link2Val });
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = OUTPUT, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

return this.ExecuteNonQueryWithOutput("CreateRecord", parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: Where are you actually defining the parameters to pass to the proc?

Comment: Does `@Output` need to be declared?

Comment: @ChrisLively I think they're in the `parameters` array. More importantly he just has `set @output = 0` but he hasn't declared it anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisLively it looks like that is likely in the GenerateCommand method, but it is hidden from us

Comment: Sorry guys, it is declared. I've updated the post. Typo when I was writing up the question. Sorry!

Comment: @AaronBertrand: They should be in that array, but unless he posts the code showing that my guess is that output isn't there..

Comment: @ChrisLively - It's in the array. I'll edit the post and show that code, thanks.

Comment: Why do you have ParameterName = OUTPUT instead of ParameterName = "@Output"? Maybe you should name it something differently so you don't get confused between its name and its purpose. Maybe "@NewRecordId"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - It's currently setup as a `string const` in the class, which is set equal to `"@Output"`. That's currently why it looks like that.

Comment: @Scott: Using a const set to `@output` that is the name of a common output parameter is also a bad design...  There should never be a reason to do a global change on that string and it's not like you are really saving any time typing `@output`...

Comment: Yeah I mean, I guess it was just for if someone else came into the project, they'd know that in every procedure, they could just look for the `@Output` and know it was always going to say that as long as all of the tests passed, to check and see what the code expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous things wrong with the code that go beyond the output parameter issue.

**To answer the actual question, you are likely passing a NULL value back as the Output.  When it tries to convert this to an Int you are getting an error.**

Also the sql line:

```
IF @Link1ID = null
```

Will **ALWAYS** fail.  In SQL parlance, null is an indeterminate value, so (null != null).  The way to test for null values is to use `IS`.  For example:

```
IF (@Link1ID is null)
```

Which leads me to believe that you are actually getting a primary key violation in the sql code.

Now, onto the bigger issue.  Your C# code is flawed.  The command object is never disposed of and if there are any issues your connection object won't be disposed of either.  This will lead to fun sql errors due running out of available sql connections..

It *should* look something like the following:

```
private int ExecuteNonQueryWithOutput(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    int retval = 0;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
    using (SqlCommand command = this.GenerateCommand(procedureName, parameters)) {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        retval = (int)command.Parameters[OUTPUT].Value;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Note that this declares, uses and disposes of your connection and command objects locally.  If there is a problem this will make sure the resources are properly disposed of.

Also note that it does not use a global "connection" object.  Connection pooling offered by the operating system is incredibly efficient at opening/closing connections as needed.  Because of this the best practice is to instantiate and keep them around only long enough to deal with the current operation.  The longer it's open the more likely you'll run into issues.

Comment: Thanks for this Chris :) I am going to make the following enhancements to the way I deal with the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects after reading through this post. However, just a note on your second paragraph, I actually am passing the `@Output` parameter through the collection. I've updated my question to reflect this. All of this is working for another procedure I have that's setup the same way, just cannot figure out why it's not working for this proc.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I think my initial question was about. This works in another stored procedure, so I'm wondering why I'm getting nothing back in the `@Output` parameter. When I run through the code, and get to the line that parses this output, I can verify in the database that the correct record is there, and even run that one line of SQL that selects the correct ID as `@Output`, but for some reason it never gets returned on the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @Scott: I slipped another update in.  There are more issues with the SQL code itself.

Comment: Ah okay, I think that second update might be the root cause, because then it would always slip to the `ELSE` and not be correctly selecting the record.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris. That was the root cause in the SQL, and you have also shown me a way to clean up my SQL code and make it more efficient, a true worthy StackOverflow answer :) Not only fixes my issue but makes me a better coder. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you've declared @Output. Did you mean:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateRecord] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Link1Id INT = NULL,
    @Link2Id INT = NULL,
    @Amount MONEY,
    @Output INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
```

Also I'm not 100% sure you have the syntax right for retrieving a named output parameter. But the parameter has to exist before you can reference it anyway. How did you save that stored procedure without declaring @Output?

Comment: There are all kinds of things wrong with the sproc and how it is called.

Comment: @Aaron - yes, sorry! I edited my post. I did have `@Output` declared I just missed it when I first typed it up. Stefan, how would I call this better? I'm constantly trying to learn and improve so any feedback you have would be great, thanks.